# Make inner div grow in height when outer div grows

Tags: css

I have two divs inside a parent div (see image below). When the "black" div grows in height, so does the outer "red" div, but I want to make the "green" div to grow as well. How can this be done in css?

[image]

Comment: Did you try `height:100%`? Or, is it not moving as the black `div` grows?

Comment: Search CSS multi-column layouts, either here or on Google, and you will come up with a lot of questions about this exact same thing.

Comment: Yes I have tried 100% height but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the CSS properties `table, table-row, and table-cell`. You may need to check if its supported in browsers your targeting though. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#table

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2GawC/

Comment: D: but that's unnecessary for this and table layouts are terrible!

Comment: I can't think of another way to do it? 100% divs will only ever fit content and not expand with siblings :-S

Comment: He's talking about applying table layout style to divs in CSS, not using table-based layout in HTML. There's nothing terrible about that, it's a perfectly legit solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `height:100%` it's probably not working because the parent div has a `position` attribute of `static` (default).  Apply `position:relative` to the parent and it should work. :)